# Net filter source and destination ports

Tags: linux-kernel, firewall, tcp, netfilter

I am currently building stateless firewall module at the linux Kernel, using Netfilter.
For every packet going in/out i want to extract the layer 4 source and destination ports.I want to extract it regardless of the L4 protocol.
currently i know how to extract it only based on the l4 protocol: getting the protocol header and getting the port from the header. 
I want to get it without getting the protocol type, directly from sk_buff struct.
I would like some help for this topic. tnx!

Comment: What does it mean "regardless of the L4 protocol"? Without the `if`-statements like `if (iphdr->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP)`? Why are you embarrassed by this approach?

Comment: Hey, the reason i dont want to use it as i dont know ahead what the layer 4 protocol of the incoming/outcoming packet is : whether is udp,tcp,icmp etc.
i dont want to condition every layer 4 protocol exists.

Comment: *"I don't want"* is not a reason. **Fields that contain ports belong to the L4-protocol header**. Ports in each L4-protocol header can be placed differently. So depends on (implies a condition) L4-protocol type you can access its header fields (like ports). If you don't know which L4-protocol is in your packet - you don't know where these ports are placed in packet. Is it clear for you?